# PassportJS and Redirects

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When a user visits my site, they can visit some partials without needing to log in.  If they log in (through a modal), passportjs redirects them back to the main page.  If I remove the redirect, passport fails the login altogether.

Does anyone have code which they can share that will bypass the required redirect or redirect the user to the current url which they're on (without redirecting to '/')?

Below is my code which calls passport then does the "required" redirect:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/', 
    failureRedirect : '/', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yah -- you don't *have* to redirect when authentication is performed -- check out the code below for an example:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
);
```

Comment: Thanks rdegges!  This was very helpful.  I don't have enough points to vote yet; or else I would.